# Show that a graph has at least two different dual graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

If I have a planar Graph $G(V,E)$, it is easy to obtain the dual $G^{*}$ graphically.

But how is it possible to show formal that $G$ has at least two different dual graphs?

Is it enough to find an isomorphic graph to $G^{*}$?

For example the graph with $V$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} and $E$ =
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)}

How to show formally that this graph has at least two different dual graphs?

Comment: The point is that in some cases, you get different (and often *non-isomorphic*) dual graphs from different plane embeddings of the same planar graph.

Comment: For this purpose it is sufficient to construct two non-isomorphic dual graphs. Your  particular graph is considered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph#Uniqueness).